# Godot - Get button node in click event not working

Tags: godot, gdscript

How we can get the button reference on the event function that is connected?
My connect signals never works

```
extends PanelContainer

onready var hbox_container = $ScrollContainer/HBoxContainer
var btn 

func _ready():
    createbutton()

func createbutton():
    btn = Button.new()
    btn.set_name("button 1")
    btn.text = "button 1"
    hbox_container.add_child(btn)
    btn.connect("toggled", self, "button_toggled", [btn])

func button_toggled(toggled, target):
    print("which button = ", target.get_name())
    if toggled == true:
        print("Button ist pressed")
    else: 
        print("Button is released")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the toggle_mode

```
extends PanelContainer

var btn:Button

func _ready():
    createbutton()

func createbutton():
    btn = Button.new()
    btn.set_name("button 1")
    btn.text = "button 1"

    btn.toggle_mode = true

    add_child(btn)
    btn.connect("toggled", self, "button_toggled", [btn])

func button_toggled(toggled, target):
    print("which button = ", target.get_name())
    if toggled == true:
        print("Button ist pressed")
    else: 
        print("Button is released")
```

I removed `onready var hbox_container = $ScrollContainer/HBoxContainer`
 for brevity

It is best to type variable to get autocomplete to work like `var btn:Button` done above.